# StyleableProperty JavaFx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Can somebody explain to me what a StyleableProperty is in JavaFX and how it can be used? I can't find anything about this in the web.

Answer (score 0):

`com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty`

So it's inner non-public class. It's better not to use it directly in apps.

Answer (score 0):

This class is used to link a property to a css attribute so you can change/override a css attribute value dynamically at runtime.

Here is an example how to use it:
http://www.guigarage.com/2014/03/javafx-css-utilities/

Answer (score 0):

StyleableProperty allows a javafx.beans.property to be styled from CSS.

you can find what you want in this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html